# How to use mongo URI in mongoLab and Heroku server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, uri, mlab

I am using MongoDb and Nodejs. Nodejs is hosted on Heroku server and Mongodb is in MongoLab through Heroku add-on.

After installed MongoLab add-on, I received this URI:

```
mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds053148.mongolab.com:53148/heroku_app18934798
```

I do not know how to use this URI, please help?
Where to put it? what is `<dbuser>:<dbpassword`

This is my config which is concern to mongoDB in `locallhost`

In `server.js`

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
    config = require('./config/config')[env],
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var db = mongoose.connect(config.db);
```

In `express.js`

```
app.use(express.session({
            secret: 'thissecret',
            key:'express.sid',
            store: new mongoStore({
                url: config.db,
                collection: 'sessions'
            })
        }));
```

In `config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    development: {
        db: 'mongodb://localhost/mean-dev',
        root: rootPath,
        app: {
            name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Development'
        },
        facebook: {
            clientID: "APP_ID",
            clientSecret: "APP_SECRET",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
        }

    },
    test: {
        db: 'mongodb://localhost/mean-test',
        root: rootPath,
        app: {
            name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Test'
        },
        facebook: {
            clientID: "APP_ID",
            clientSecret: "APP_SECRET",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
        }

    },
    production: {
        db: 'mongodb://localhost/mean',
        root: rootPath,
        app: {
            name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Production'
        },
        facebook: {
            clientID: "APP_ID",
            clientSecret: "APP_SECRET",
            callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to the database using the following:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds053148.mongolab.com:53148/<database name>');
```

But in your case I would replace `mongodb://localhost/<database name>` with `mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds053148.mongolab.com:53148/<database name>`

Answer (score 1):

```
mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

MONGOLAB_URI = "mongodb://<admin>:<admin>@ds3232.mlab.com:23213/abcd"

mongoose.connect(MONGOLAB_URI || mongoURI)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what your solution is doing instead of just pasting a piece of code.

Comment: this is actually the best answer IMO, also pretty obvious by reading the code @N

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
development: {
    db: 'mongodb://your_user_name:your_password@ds053148.mongolab.com:53148/heroku_app18934798',
    root: rootPath,
    app: {
        name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Development'
    },
    facebook: {
        clientID: "APP_ID",
        clientSecret: "APP_SECRET",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
    }

},
test: {
    db: 'mongodb://your_user_name:your_password@ds053148.mongolab.com:53148/heroku_app18934798',
    root: rootPath,
    app: {
        name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Test'
    },
    facebook: {
        clientID: "APP_ID",
        clientSecret: "APP_SECRET",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
    }

},
production: {
    db: 'mongodb://your_user_name:your_password@ds053148.mongolab.com:53148/heroku_app18934798',
    root: rootPath,
    app: {
        name: 'MEAN - A Modern Stack - Production'
    },
    facebook: {
        clientID: "APP_ID",
        clientSecret: "APP_SECRET",
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback"
    }

}
};
```

Paste this in your config.js file and replace `your_user_name` by your username and replace `your_password` by your password to get the connection.